# Undefined Variable error when passing in callback of rememberForever : Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **What I am doing ?**

I pass `CategoryID` parameter value as default value to the `where` clause

```
public function SubCategories($CategoryID)
{
    $CandSubCat = \Cache::rememberForever('CandSubCat' . $CategoryID, function() {
        return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model
            ::where("CategoryID", "=", $CategoryID)
            ->with("SubCategories")
            ->first();
    });

    return view("Skill.SubCategory.List", array("CandSubCat" => $CandSubCat));
}
```

### **Question:**

Why it gives runtime error, saying:

> Undefined variable: CategoryID in Where Clause?

Comment: You are using anonymous function as second parameter. This function has not global scope, you must pass a variable to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the variable to the scope of function with the `use` keyword like this:

```
public function SubCategories($CategoryID)
{
    $CandSubCat = \Cache::rememberForever('CandSubCat' . $CategoryID, function() use($CategoryID) {
        return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model
            ::where("CategoryID", "=", $CategoryID)
            ->with("SubCategories")
            ->first();
    });

    return view("Skill.SubCategory.List", array("CandSubCat" => $CandSubCat));
}
```